# How to Manually Check for Duplicates in a 3x3 Array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, unique, nested-loops, function-definition

I am working on an assignment where I write a bool function that checks for duplicates in an array.

I want to see if any numbers between 1 and 9 appear more than once, then return true or a statement if they don't. However, I am stuck on going through the array and completing a check. How would I incorporate the array from my make_array() function into this.. the bool statement is supposed to check that function but no matter how I write it, it doesn't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


int numbers[3][3] = {};

void make_array() 
{
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
  {
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) 
    {
       numbers[row][column] = rand() % 9 + 1;
       cout << numbers[row][column] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

bool appears_once()
{
    bool unique = true;

    for ( int copy_row = 0; copy_row < 3; copy_row++ )
    {
        for ( int copy_column = copy_row + 1; copy_column < 3; copy_column++ )
        {
            if (numbers[copy_row][copy_row] == numbers[ copy_column][ copy_column] ) 
            unique = true;
            cout << unique;
        }
    }

    return !unique;
    
}
int main() 
{
  int row, column = 0;
  srand(time(0));
  make_array();
  appears_once();
}
```

Comment: `return false;` kicks out of the function immediately on the first non-duplicate. Move that to the end of the function, replace the `return 0;`, where it means "If I haven't already returned true, I must not have found a duplicate."

Comment: Tactical note: Familiarize yourself with the debugger that came with your development environment. With a debugger you can execute the program line by line and watch what the program does as it it does it. Stepping through a problem spot in your code often solves even the nastiest programming problems almost instantly. When you see the program do something you did not expect like stroe the wrong value or take the wrong path, stop and determine why it happened. You've probably found a bug.

Comment: Side note: Since you are randomly generating the input take a look at [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle). The example at the bottom of the linked page shows how to easily guarantee no duplicates without having to generate and check over and over again. This is known as the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: I am using repl.it. It has a debugger, which I used but nonetheless I am trying to understand which is why iIam here looking for human explanation.. @user4581301

Comment: There is a danger in that. When you ask questions that could have been solved with common tools they tend to be poorly received. If the ratio between well-received and poorly-received questions dips too low you'll find the rate at which you can ask questions is reduced to about one question every six months, and once this happens it is extremely hard to regain the ability to ask questions frequently because your ability to ask questions that could tip the balance back in your favour is dramatically reduced.

Comment: Woah, I never knew that... makes much sense

Comment: You also have to be careful when deleting poorly received questions. Deleted questions are still used when computing the ratio. Your best bet is to improve a question and try and bring it around. If the question has been deleted, no one can vote it up and it sits there (as far as I've been able to tell) forever. On the other hand, if you can't improve the question to make it positive, you're better off deleting it to prevent it from getting more downvotes.

Comment: Noting the similarity of the fill routine and the check routine makes me think you could notice duplicates already when you fill the array ;-). Heck, you don't even need an array!! (OK, I know, it's an assignment and I should distinguish between the working code (the check) and the "test harness" (the filling and call) but still ;-).

Answer (score 2):

This inner for loop

```
for (int ccolumn = check_row + 1; ccolumn < 3; ccolumn++) 
{
  if (check_row != ccolumn) 
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }

}
```

does not make a sense. At least there are no comparisons of elements of the array.

The function can be defined for example the following way

```
bool appears_once()
{
    bool unique = true;

    for ( size_t i = 0; unique && i < 9; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; unique && j < 9; j++ )
        {
            if ( numbers[i / 3][i % 3] == numbers[ j / 3 ][ j % 3] ) unique = false;
        }
    }

    return unique;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you, but I do not really understand this code or what is happening in it. How would i translate this?

Comment: @beginnercoderuh For each element in the array the nested loops check whether there is another element in the array after the current element that is equal to the current element.

Comment: Why not cast 2 dimensional array to 1 dimensional one first?

Comment: @convert As I showed there is no need to do this.

Comment: @convert a 2D array is not a 1D array. The cast would violate strict aliasing.

Comment: How would I incorporate the array from my make_array() function into this.. the bool statement is supposed to check that function but no matter how I write it, it doesn't.

Comment: @beginnercoderuh I have not understood what you mean. I showed a ready to use function that is declared the same way as shown in your question.

Comment: @beginnercoderuh You can check the function  writing in main printf( "%s\n", appears_once() ? "true" : "false" );

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow I know, but by converting to 1D array you don´t need to do al that calculations.

Comment: @user4581301 But that strict aliasing just gives you a warning not an  error, or did something changed in c++17+?

Comment: @convert probably doesn't give you either because you'll have hidden the error behind a cast. It's been against the rules since day one, but it's also one of those classic, "Probably gonna work, but not guaranteed to work" things because of the way a 2D array is going to be stored unless the compiler writer was a madman or trying to solve a really interesting problem.

Comment: @user4581301 But NxM array of whatewer type T is just a sequence of N*M values of type T in memory. Did something changed since C++11?

Comment: @convert To my knowledge (don't have an old enough Standard document to look it up in and link/quote) it's always been UB, but A) the kind of UB that "just works" and B) the restrictions have been weakening over time. Maybe in C++23 (or some part of C++20 I've missed or misinterpreted) the types will be deemed similar enough to guarantee the behaviour.

Comment: @user4581301 Always thought there is some standard how C structs represented in memory, since they are often used to store data in binary files.